# Join 2 коннектов

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Столкнулся с проблемой при выборке данных MySql 5.6
основная часть данных храниться в одном коннекте и справочники хранятся в другом коннекте можно ли объединить join запросы с разных коннектов

к примеру  коннект где есть phone

```
 id phone id_city 
 1   5555    1
 2   6666    2
 3   7777    3
```

коннект где есть город City

```
 id_city   name    
 1        Лондон    
 2        Париж   
 3        Варшава
```

если бы был один коннект то выборка была бы следующей

```
select *
from phone
left join City  on City.id_city = phone.id_city
```

но как сделать когда их 2 ?

YII2

Comment: дак если у вас все справочники хранятся таким образом, то как данная проблема решается в других частях приложния?

Comment: если сервер один а просто разные базы, то можно делать к любому конекту. главное чтобы у юзера были доступы к обоим базам. Если разные сервера,  то делайте 2 запроса. все равно же данные потом обрабатывать в php